# Angular 2/4 : how to change route without recreating the component

Tags: javascript, angular, ngroute

I have several routes to the same component (namely /projects, /projects/create, /projects/:id and children, all pointing to my ProjectComponent).
When navigating between /projects/:id with only :id changing everything is fine, I can subscribe to the params and update my content accordingly, but when I navigate from /projects to /projects/create or to /projects/:id, the component is recreated.

Is there any way to navigate to a route pointing to the same component without it being recreated ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to an external URL from angular2 route without using component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a custom `RouteReuseStrategy`

Create a service implementing the `RouteReuseStrategy`:

```
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        if (!route.routeConfig) return null;
        return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }
}
```

And add this provider to the `@NgModule`:

```
providers: [
    {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy}
]
```

You can adjust the `CustomReuseStrategy` to only have certain paths where the component can be reused, but I'll leave that up to you to find out how.

[source](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks it's perfect, I actually came across this article but I dismissed it because the whole attach/detach/store/retrieve thing wasn't what I was looking for. I need to pay more attention.