# window.open() in Angular 4.4.6 Resolver

Tags: angular

I have a task to implement opening a url in a different tab when clicking on an item in a dropdown menu using Angular 4.4.6
I have a hack solution using a dummy component with a window.open() method to get the job done. But I tend to think there is a more elegant solution to this. Tried a hack using a derivative of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component) answer, which I believe is close, but I'm missing something. 
Here is a snippet of what I am trying:

app.module.ts provider excerpt of Resolver

```
    {
        provide: 'urlRedirectResolver', useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
            //Something like this
            window.open((route.data as any).otherUrl);
            //OR
            window.location.href = window.open((route.data as any).otherUrl); 
        }
    }
```

app.router.ts route excerpt of Implementation

```
    path: 'SomeComponentURL', component: SomeComponent, resolve: {
        url: 'urlRedirectResolver'
    },
    data: {
        otherUrl: (document.location.hash != '#/SomeComponent')
            ? 'someContent.pdf' : history.back()
    }
```

If the question is too vague please let me know and I'll try to revise it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<a target="_blank" routerLink="...">`?

Comment: That actually works for other requirements in the app, but the dropdown list is generated dynamically :-) I'm trying to solve this without creating another component and using only a resolver

Comment: I don't see how the fact that it's generated dynamically prevents using target="_blank". A resolve is used to load data needed by a routed component. Not to open a link in a new tab.

Comment: Hmm, are you referring to something like window.open((route.data as any).otherUrl, '_blank') cause I tried that already and it didn't work. It just made the page blink

Comment: No. I'm telling you that you're using a resolve for something it's not supposed to be used for. Instead, you should use target="_blank" on your links.

Comment: Not all links do the same thing. I get what you are saying, I'm just posting a question and looking for feedback thanks

Comment: Then set the target to _blank on links that must open in a new tab, and set it to _self for links that must not.