# Angular 4 route to external url

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a route to an external URL. Below is my example so far.

The error I am getting is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'https:/google.com'
>
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'https:/google.com'

here is my code

```
ViolatorLink() {
    this.router.navigate(['https://www.google.com/'], {
        queryParams: {mid: this.mid}
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can refer below link in detail
[Route to external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component/40395382)

Answer (score 9):

Ideally, you should use the `window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";` for your external URL calls because `this.router.navigate` looks the URL in `angular routings`.

Your function should be like:

```
ViolatorLink() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  }
```

Comment: why are you posting same answer agian

Comment: I didn't check, you have posted something. Only one solution is for the problem so our answers are similar. @Sajeetharan

Comment: Thanks for the response as well. Maybe you could help some of my additional questions above? @Rohit.007

Comment: Yes please ask your queries

Comment: okay, I Just checked your responses in another answer. You can take all the parameters in your `ViolatorLink()` function and you can concate your parameters in the URL e.g. `window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/id/" + yourId` where `yourId` is a variable.

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote-up if it worked for you?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use instead of **`this.router.navigate`**

```
window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
```

**`this.router.navigate`** will navigate to only the elements configured in your router config module. So you are getting the error above.

Comment: awesome, now how can I navigate the url to www.google.com/ and have this.mid value come after?

Comment: if you want to pass parameter that should be with the href

Comment: what do you want to actually do?

Comment: i have an external link foo.com and I need to pass params to it like www.foo.com/11/

Comment: what is the benefit of that? it dpeneds on the external sites as well

Comment: because I have to create a link that opens a sister site and pass params into it.

Comment: so how do i configure router config module?  And where that does live? did you mean app.routing.module? please advise - thanks

Answer (score -4):

```
<a [href]="https://www.yourExternalURL.com">
```

I am typing extra characters because SO now needs at least 30 characters in an answer.

Comment: SO needs 30 characters so you'd explain your answer instead of just posting code(as you did). Also this is only helpful if you want to redirect to an external URL directly from the view. If instead you want to redirect from the component then this doesn't help.