# Redirect to URL outside the Angular app but on the same domain

Tags: angular

**Within *angular routing*** is there any way to *redirect* to an *external directory* on the same domain. I have a WordPress blog and angular app I want it to use same domain rather than a subdomain.

**Example**

- http://example.com --> Angular App
- http://example.com/blog --> Wordpress Blog

*Please help me with your suggestions.*

Comment: 2 solutions come to my mind, you could either put the blog in a iframe, or let the server redirect the url to the blog instead of the angular file..

Comment: simply redirect `window.location.href = 'your_url';` ?

Comment: Possible douplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component/40395382

Comment: Thanks, @Ploppy, I already aware of those solutions, but I want something else

Comment: thanks, @Denisx, your solution will work with an external URL but not with URL in the same domain

Comment: @JacopoSciampi This is not a duplication I ask something else

Comment: @KesaraWimal look the comments, angular's router navigate just into your domain, so if, for example, you have an angular app running in the port 3000 and a blog running on a port 3500, you can't use router

Comment: @JacopoSciampi can you please explain it more, how to redirect to internal URL rather than an external URL

Comment: @KesaraWimal like @Denisx said, `window.location.href = 'your_url';`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi that is working with external URL, not with internal ones

Comment: I am also facing this difficulty, window.location.href does not work when redirecting on the same domain. Please advise?

Comment: Digging this up because I'm also facing the same problem. Seems to be unsolved even on Angular's github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15015

Comment: @VolatileRig: What error do you get with `window.location.href = 'https://....'`?

Comment: try 
window.location.href = 'your URL';
location.reload(true);

Comment: @KesaraWimal Ports are used in development modes, not production!

Answer (score 7):

I understand why you wanna do this with Angular router. Navigating to an external url from an Angular application is something quite easy. Using `window.location` or an anchor tag is straight forward, but it has a **big disadvantage**, it *bypasses the Angular Router*.

@Adrian proposed a nice and generic way of navigating to an external url using the Angular Router which is written inside [Using the Angular Router to navigate to external links](https://adrianfaciu.dev/posts/angular-router-external-links/). I like his implementation which looks clean and correct. He prepared the final result in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-external-links) too.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to actually try this impl, but I feel like this is the most "correct" way to implement it because it doesn't bypass the Router. Actually, I hadn't considered the route guards at all, but now that I have, there's no doubt that I want to continue using the router. :)

Answer (score 2):

If understood correctly, it should work with redirection based on content type.

- Solution:

> Redirects (301, 302, 303, 307) to internal/external page or file, based on domain and path:

- Github - [TYPO3.UrlForwarding](https://github.com/patrickbroens/TYPO3.UrlForwarding)
- See - [Full documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/url_forwarding/)

---

> Other option is to use DNS redirects at [redirect.center](http://redirect.center/) as an example.

---

> Last and final, to use WordPress plugin which at first look seems to have many options to try out.

- More at - [https://redirection.me](https://redirection.me/)

---

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `window.open(url, '_blank');` it will open new tab with url that set in to it

Answer (score 1):

The angular router is meant to provide the routes within the angular app and has no inherent external routing.

You could route to an almost empty component that redirects to your external link. That seems to be the simplest solution.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';    

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**blog.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: ''
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    window.location.href = 'http://example.com/blog';
  }
}
```

*PS: Ensure you can access your wordpress installation without being redirected to the angular app by your server.*

Comment: I think question is asked for angularjs1.x.

Comment: @pavinan It's been tagged as both. Which seems kinda weird, since they are mutually exclusive tags. That said I am not familiar with `angularjs`. So maybe someone who does can use this answer as inspiration or point out any similarities.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use redirect to function like the following code sample.

```js
$routeProvider.when("/blog", {
  redirectTo: function () {
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/blog";
    // remove below line if it is not working.
    return "/some redirecting animation page";
  }
});
```

if using state provider.

```js
var aboutState = {
  name: 'blog',
  url: '/blog',
  redirectTo: function () {
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/blog";
    // remove below line if it is not working.
    return "/some redirecting animation page";
  }
}
```