# Blank screen while loading angular project after deploying in server and redirecting from parent project?

Tags: angular, devops

I have two angular project (parent project and child project),both are deployed in server, where child is deployed as sub directory inside parent and a URL is generated [image](abcd.com/strategy) for child project. Once I redirect from parent to child I'm getting console error and once after I hard reload its working.

Kindly help me with the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to URL outside the Angular app but on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271546/redirect-to-url-outside-the-angular-app-but-on-the-same-domain)

Comment: no... I have done the deployment its opening in a new URL, but for the first time it gives blank screen once hard reload it works