# How to setup dynamic Base URL to route user to some specific Component

Tags: angular, url, angular-router

I'm looking for some help regarding the use of dynamic words in my Base URL.

Consider for example Slack. If i write **abcd.slack.com** it finds a work space name **abcd** and redirects me to the login page of the work space. I need a similar implementation in my Angular website. I don't know how to implement such thing. In Angular routing i can only provide the paths which comes after the base URL. How can i implement such thing that also works on my production environment.

For example 
This is the usual URL in our development environment
http://localhost:4200/signin

Can i do something like this

http://xxxx.localhost:4200/signin

where i can set **xxxx** as my dynamic data to perform some backend queries

I think is the same as 
**abcd.slack.com**

Comment: So what exactly is the problem???  What have you actually tried,and what specific problems did you encounter?  Please update your post with an [mcve] and/or more .details

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I just found a similar thing happening in Slack, that's what i need in my website. I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location` to redirect to URL other than routes defined by angular application:

```
window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example on how to use this URL or some word in the URL to render a component in Angular? Can we put if/else condition in our Routes?

Comment: @SaadAshfaq I thought you need dynamic base URL. Usually that is done inside some business logic code and not with routes. If you want to do it with routes, you can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40421975/10699402

Comment: Yes. Definitely i need dynamic base URL, but based on that i need to render some component as well. You can see Slack as an example. I've explained it's working above.

Comment: I've updated the question. Maybe now it can help you understand what i'm asking for.