# Angular routing redirect directory path with '**' pattern matching

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a situation where the user is to be routed to a directory structure path within angular routing mechanism. 
For example:
The host is abc.com. The angular routing will work on this host.
Then I have defined a path in angular routing with pattern matching such as "**" which matches every pattern if none is found.
But I have a situation where I need to redirect to "abc.com/safari".
The angular routing is blocking this and redirecting me to the "**" path and that component.

Have researched on stack overflow and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component).
I am trying to implement these options, but to no avail. Can someone please help!!

How can I activate the abc.com/safari route without changing my host and angular routing blocking it?

Comment: Have you tried putting `'*'` entry to the bottom of your routes?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to navigate only between your host, then it's very important in which position you put your routes. Try to put that routes in different order. Would be also nice if you will insert some source code to properly analyse your issue.

Comment: @PatrykPanek How will the ordering of the routes matter when we have not defined "safari" in our route paths, hence "safari" will not match any routes except for "\**".

Comment: @Bartu I am looking into it and will update you.