# How can I navigate to an external URL using angular Router

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I have been stuck in this for a long time. How can I replace `window.location.href = url` to use Angular routing?

```js
checkforStoredLocale() {
  if (this.storedlocale && this.storedlocale !== this.localeId) {
    this.consoleService.consoleMessage('redirecting');
    let port = this.location.port.length > 0 ? `:${this.location.port}` : '';
    let url = `${this.location.protocol}//${this.location.hostname}${port}${this.baseHref}${this.storedlocale}${this.location.pathname}`;
    this.consoleService.consoleMessage(url);
    // this.route.navigateByUrl(url);
    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to an external URL from angular2 route without using component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component)

Comment: Angular Router is reserved for in app routing, you need to go old school js (as you already did) for location changes.

Comment: @MarcSances no it  doesn't if anything your suggested link also uses the window.location.href, which i don't want to

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu do you mean to say there is no way I could redirect to the said url without using that window.location.href please?

Comment: Exactly, not with any builtin Angular component at least.