# How to route to another website when user Logout - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I'm trying to redirect the page to `Google`'s home page when user's logout.
For that, I'm using the following function:

```
$(window.location)[0].replace(this.urlLogout);
```

But instead of being redirected to `Google`, I'm getting this route in the `URL` browser:

```
http://localhost:4200/www.google.com.br
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to an external URL from angular2 route without using component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component)

Comment: Seems you're redirecting relativley. How do you build `this.urlLogout`?

Comment: this.urlLogout = this.$auth.estilo.des_url_logout;

I'm getting this from an API that contains all the configuration informations, including the URL that will be redirected the website when logout..

Comment: window.location.replace(this.urlLogout) this should work, make sure this.urlLogout has http:// or https:// if not you can add it client side or if you have control at API side then there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are missing the protocol part, either try to get that from your API or you can do it on the client-side.

```
window.location.replace(`https://${this.urlLogout}`);
```

Or if you are sure about the protocol on your website and the redirecting domain and both of them are the same, you can do like this

```
window.location.replace(`${window.location.protocol}//${this.urlLogout}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location.replace(this.urlLogout) this should work, make sure this.urlLogout has http:// or https:// if not you can add it client side or if you have control at API side then there

@Lokesh Daiya

That worked for me, it was a missing http:// protocol in front of the URL.
That's why I was getting this error.

Thank you!